# How to push values to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to push values to a dynamic multi-dimensional array. This is the code i have:

```
function compareNumbers(){
    var count = $('.finishedRow').length;
    var inputtedNums = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
        $('.finishedRow').eq(i).find('li').each(function(j){
            inputtedNums[i].push($(this).text());
        });
    }
    console.log(inputtedNums);
}
```

So say there are, for example, 3 `finishedRow` selectors and each `finishedRow` selector contains 4 `li` elements with values of `first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth`. I want my `inputtedNums` variable to look like:

```
inputtedNums = [
   ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"],
   ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], 
   ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"] 
]
```

As my code is now I get the error: `Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize every nested array first.

```
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    inputtedNums[i] = new Array();
    $('.finishedRow').eq(i).find('li').each(function(j) {
        inputtedNums[i].push($(this).text());
    });
}
```

Comment: I knew the solution was probably simple but didn't think it would be that simple! Thanks

Comment: hi how can i put variable key into your solution?

Comment: I have similar code as below but I am getting erro: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference      
              $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                    debugger;
                    if (item.Dataset != '' && item.Dataset >= 0) {
                        var date = item.DateCreated.replace(/\//g, "").replace('Date', " 
              ").replace('(', "").replace(')', "");
                        arrObject[parseInt(date)].push($(parseFloat(item.Dataset)));
                    }
                });